# how can I fix this ''name is not defined''

Tags: python, lmfit

I am newbie in python I have this code i want to use subclass lmfit.models and implement a guess method,

```
class DecayingSineModel():

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        def decaying_sine(self, x, ampl, offset, freq, x0, tau):
            return ampl * np.sin((x - x0)*freq) * np.exp(-x/tau) + offset

        super(DecayingSineModel, self).__init__(decaying_sine, *args, **kwargs)

    def pset(param, value):
        params["%s%s" % (self.prefix, param)].set(value=value)

    def guess(self, data, **kwargs):         
        params = self.make_params()
        pset("ampl", np.max(data) - np.min(data))
        pset("offset", np.mean(data))
        pset("freq", 1)
        pset("x0", 0)
        pset("tau", 1)
        return lmfit.models.update_param_vals(params, self.prefix, **kwargs)

sp = DecayingSineModel()
params = sp.guess(y, x=x)
fit = sp.fit(y, params, x=x)
```

and i am recieving following error 
   the error that i am recieving
[the image of error that i recieved is in this address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dbHr.png)

Comment: Is this how you indented your code, because this can explain it.

Comment: Please post an exact copy of your code, since it is very weird right now...

Comment: Is the call to `super` inside your `__init__` method?  With the broken indentation it's impossible to tell.  Similarly, is `sp = DecayingSineModel()` inside the class body?  Or is it outside of the class?

Comment: Voting to close.  Without knowing the exact indentation that OP is using, we can only guess at where the error is coming from.

Comment: You say you want to 'subclass lmfit.models' but your `class` declaration doesn't mention lmfit. I also wonder why you don't use the simple pattern for describing models, in the introduction for this software.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want your `DecayingSineWave` to inherit from `lmfit.Model`.  As others have pointed out there are a number of other problems with your code, including the fact that your `pset` references `self` but doesn't have it passed in and yet you call `pset`, not `self.pset`.  Your model function `decaying_sine` should *not* have `self`.

A cleaned-up version:

```
import numpy as np
import lmfit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DecayingSineModel(lmfit.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def decaying_sine(x, ampl, offset, freq, x0, tau):
            return ampl * np.sin((x - x0)*freq) * np.exp(-x/tau) + offset
        super(DecayingSineModel, self).__init__(decaying_sine, *args, **kwargs)

    def guess(self, data, x=None, **kwargs):
        ampl = np.max(data) - np.min(data)
        offset = np.mean(data)
        params = self.make_params(ampl=ampl, offset=offset, freq=1, x0=0, tau=1)
        return lmfit.models.update_param_vals(params, self.prefix, **kwargs)

sp = DecayingSineModel()

x = np.linspace(0, 25, 201)
noise = np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.25)
y = 2 + 7*np.sin(1.6*(x-0.2)) * np.exp(-x/18) + noise

params = sp.guess(y, x=x)
result = sp.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

gives a report of:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(decaying_sine)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 83
    # data points      = 201
    # variables        = 5
    chi-square         = 39.266
    reduced chi-square = 0.200
    Akaike info crit   = -318.220
    Bayesian info crit = -301.703
[[Variables]]
    ampl:     6.92483967 +/- 0.123863 (1.79%) (init= 12.59529)
    offset:   1.96307863 +/- 0.031684 (1.61%) (init= 2.139916)
    freq:     1.60060819 +/- 0.001775 (0.11%) (init= 1)
    x0:       0.19650313 +/- 0.010267 (5.23%) (init= 0)
    tau:      18.3528781 +/- 0.614576 (3.35%) (init= 1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(ampl, tau)                 = -0.781 
    C(freq, x0)                  =  0.750
```

and
[image]

Comment: Yeah, Thanks but after do this i recieved this error again.

Comment: Hm, I doubt that: when I try your code I do not get the NameError error.    But, as others have pointed out, there are several other problems with your code.  I updated my answer to give a working version.

Comment: @M Newville thanks for your reply i dont know why i am recieving this error even with your working version, maybe there is  another problem, i am using Python 2.7.14 in widows 7, is it possible that because of this i have this problems.

Comment: post full, exact code that shows the problem and full, exact error messages.

Comment: i am using just your working version, and i updated my error image in question

Comment: try again... `super(DecayingSineWave, ...` needs to be indented properly, to be within `def __init__()`.